# Around the invariant basis property

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras

Hi everybody,

recall that a ring $A$ with unit has the invariant basis property if all bases of a given f.g. free $A$-module have the same number of elements.
It is equivalent to say that every invertible matrix with entries in $A$ is a square matrix.

It is known that if for all $n\geq 1,$ every surjective endomorphism of $A^n$ is bijective, then $A$ has the invariant basis property.

Q1: is the converse true? Another way to put this is: if $A$ has the invariant basis property, and if $e_1,...,e_n$ span $A^n$, is it a basis of $A^n$?

Q2: Assume that $A$ has the invariant basis property. Is it true that if $e_1,....,e_m\in A^n$ are linearly independent, then $m\leq n$ ?

Q3: Assume that $A$ has the invariant basis property. Is it true that if $e_1,....,e_m\in A^n$ span $A^n$, then $m\geq n$ ?

Thanks!

greg

Comment: I am pretty sure that the answer to Q1 is no, according to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stably_finite_ring . This is not a counterexample, though...

Comment: A counterexample can apparently be found in: P. M. Cohn, "Some remarks on the invariant basis property", Topology 5 (1966), 215-228. I do not have this paper.

Comment: Thanks for the reference. Apparently, all my questions are answered (by the negative) on this paper. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Mmmmh, finally, I think that the counterexamples in this paper do NOT
satisfy IBN, but I will have to read it more carefully.

Comment: Counterexample to Q2: Let $A$ be a noncommutative polynomial ring over $\mathbb Z$ in $X$ and $Y$, i.e. the "group ring" of a free monoid on two generators. The left ideal (submodule of $A$) generated by $X$ and $Y$ is isomorphic to $A^2$, but $A$ has the IBP because it admits a unital homomorphism to $\mathbb Z$.

Comment: Q1, if true, implies Q3. (Use a surjection $A^m\to A^n$, $m<n$, to make a surjection $A^n\to A^n$ that cannot be an iso.)

Comment: Ok, here is a counterexample to Q1.

Let $A$ be a noncommutative polynomial ring over $\mathbb{Z}$ in $X$ et $Y$, and let $B=A/(XY-1)$.

Let $x$ and $y$ be the images of $X$ and $Y$ in $B$. 

Let $u$ be the left multiplication by $x$ in $B$, and let $v$ be the left multiplication by $y$. Then $u\circ v=Id_B$ so $u$ is surjective, and $B$-linear (I'm considering right modules). However,$1-yx$ is a nonzero element of the kernel of û^, since $u(1-yx)=x-xyx=x-x=0$.

Finally, $B$ satisfies IBN since evaluation at $(1,1)$ is a ring morphism to $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: There is still one question left:

is it possible to find a ring $A$ with IBN and a free $A$-module $M$ of rank $n$ such that $M$ is generated by strictly less than $n$ elements ? (e.g. for $n=2$ ?)